# How Load a Theme For Path

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-theming

I like Context if Path /gallery Load A New Theme example "Bartik" Other page load "Omega" Theme

I Install the "[Context Condition Theme](https://drupal.org/project/context_condition_theme)" Modules But it does not working

What's your recommendation?

Comment: See also: [How do I change a theme based on the URL?](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/812/how-do-i-change-a-theme-based-on-the-url) at Drupal SE.

Comment: you can using context modules https://www.drupal.org/project/context

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use can use [ThemeKey](https://drupal.org/project/themekey) module.

Enable ThemeKey module and its required sub modules, then go to the config page at `admin/config/user-interface/themekey`. Here you will see may options for switching the theme.

As you required there is an option `path:node_alias` so select this option and also set the value as you want like you say `/gallery` and then select the theme you want to enable at this url.

For wildcard path use this setting as you required `web/*`:

```
Property: drupal:path
Operator: =
Value: %wildcard

Property: drupal:path:wildcard
Wildcard: wildcard
Operator: ~
Value: /^web/.*
```

Like this image reference:

[image: wildcards for ThemeKey]

Comment: i have update my post for you this example solve you taks. this example switch the when url become like as you want {web/test1 , web/test2 web/test3 }

Comment: I simply cannot get this to work in a vanilla Drupal 7 on simplytest.me (https://simplytest.me/project/drupal/7.67?add[]=themekey&add[]=pathauto&add[]=token&add[]=devel&add[]=admin_menu)