# Drupal ThemeKey: how to set a theme based on path

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I am using Drupal 7. I read this post:

[How Load a Theme For Path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20472244/how-load-a-theme-for-path)

so I did tests but it did not work.

Basically, I created a role called editor. My website has its own theme (it is a sub-theme of Bootstrap theme https://www.drupal.org/project/bootstrap).

When I sign in as editor and go to page `/admin/content` to see a list of nodes, the page uses the Bootstrap sub-theme. I want to use Seven for `/admin/content`.

In ThemeKey, I have this rule only:

```
Property: drupal:path
Operator: =
Value: admin/content
Theme: Seven
```

However, I am unable to see any change. I cleared the cache, etc. No success. This seems to be a very easy task for use/config. Don't know where I got it wrong.

Thanks for help!

Comment: Try this: [admin theme changes to default at editing page, Themekey module](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/131098/admin-theme-changes-to-default-at-editing-page-themekey-module)

Comment: BaikKo, thanks for your input. I tried that, but it is not working for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually, I used the module called Theme by Role https://www.drupal.org/project/tbr. To make it work, select "view the administration theme" permission for your role in /admin/people/permissions, which is the tip I got from many hours of tests and reading of the module's source code.

Hope this helps someone else.